# how I can make custom dialog having multiple checkboxes under multiple header text

Tags: android, checkbox, android-alertdialog, customdialog

I came across a dialog popup in `ipad` which contain multi checkboxes under multiple header titles, here is the sample dialog which i need to make in android

[image]

I can able to create multiple checkboxes under a single text title....but cannot create multi text headers in it....I read some post but which suggested to make custom views but don't knw how could I achieve it...

please do suggest some useful solutions...

Comment: use `RadioButtonGroup` and customize look

Comment: Do you have any numbers as to, how many header text you want in a dialog?

Comment: There's a few ways you could achieve this, but my suggestion would be to just create this layout as an Activity..and in your manifest change the theme of the Activity to android.theme.DIALOG

Comment: @samir  how can i add items under programmatically instead of writing each item in my xml...

Comment: @jade could you please elaborate how can i do it in activity....

Comment: @VivekSingh you could either extend Dialog and make your own, or just create a layout with radioButtons and textViews in xml just like you would for any other layout. Then create an Activity and inflate your layout via setContentView(R.layout.layout_id). But this time, in your Android Manifest add android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" to your activity tag.